# Python regex with special character, optional space and any amount of numbers

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to normalize some data in python to replace # with NUMBER if a digit follows.  Also there can be an option space between the # and the digit.  Below is what I have so far.  I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to preserve the space if it is there.

```
string_stuff = re.sub(ur'#\s?[0-9]', 'NUMBER \1', string_stuff)
```

I know the above code with match one of the numbers but how do I match all the numbers?  Below are a few examples.

```
# 334534 > NUMBER 334534
#657 > NUMBER 657
#234234234 > NUMBER 234234234
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a capture group (denoted by parens). What is inside this group will be substituted in for `\1`. You also need to match one or more digits. `+` matches one or more of the previous element.

```
string_stuff = re.sub(ur'#\s?([0-9]+)', 'NUMBER \1', string_stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `[0-9]` inside a capturing group so that you could backreference it in the replacement part.

```
string_stuff = re.sub(r'#\s?([0-9])', r'NUMBER \1', string_stuff)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fI0mX3/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lookahead to do this:

```
re.sub(ur"#(?=\s?[0-9])", "NUMBER", string_stuff)
```

This doesn't actually replace the optional space + digit -- it justs uses them to match.